# Using Python's max function when you have a variable named max?

Tags: python, scope, standard-library, built-in

Python includes the built in max() function. However, despite it being built in it is not a keyword. That is to say, you are allowed to do `max=4`. This makes sense since the maximum of something comes up a lot. But! If you use max as a variable, then it disables use of the max function in that scope.

So if you do:

```
max = 4
max(1, 2)
```

You will get an error of `int object not callable`. Again, makes sense. But is there any way to specify that you would like the max function? Like a `std.max()`? This goes for all other built in functions as well.

Comment: Do not name your variables after Python builtins, period.

Comment: @Will, I understand what you're saying but in terms of readability the names `min` and `max` are great. Thus there are times where you might create internal naming conflicts so that your API is user friendly.

Comment: It would be better to use a more descriptive name. For instance, if you have a list called `things`, use `max_thing`.

Comment: @NickChapman: If you had a `max` function, for example, if you were NumPy and you had `numpy.max`, it'd make sense to use the same name as a builtin. For `max = 4`? No way that's part of your API. Call it `max_` or something.

Comment: @user2357112 Consider the case of a keyword argument to a function. I might reasonably want to define a `get_random(min, max)`. There would never be any conflict for external users of my module, and I don't think there would be any reason to make them type `min_=` and `max_=`, but within the function body itself I'd need an alias if I wanted to use the `min` and `max` functions. (Personally, I've always used `**kwargs` in these cases to avoid shadowing, but I think it's at least debatable whether that's actually better code.)

Comment: @JeremyBanks this is exactly how this issue came up.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Why not name them `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` (or some such; there are always some good substitutes for `max` and `min` in each case). Yes you (and your user) may need to do more typing, but it's better than any work-around like `__builtin__.max` in your code.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I don't see why `lower_bound` etc is not just as user friendly as `min`, if not more so (if your user is using an IDE, he can actually get warned for using the `min` API which is annoying, but not for `lower_bound`). ps. I hope you are not saying I have a silly ideology. As for your dislike of Python, that's irrelevant. This is a question about how to do things as well as we can in Python, however much it sucks.

Comment: @NickChapman Yeah, I understand. I've wanted to name variables `class` or `max` or `file` before, too, but every language has its sacrifices you have to make. I personally use OOP-conventions for all of my names (unless I'm working on other people's code), so for me, it'd be `maxValue` or `maxThingName`. It's always good to be descriptive. If it's just a throwaway variable that doesn't need to be descriptive, call it `m`? I really, really, really wouldn't name things after builtins.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`__builtin__` (Python 2)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html) / [`builtins` (Python 3)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) module provides another way to access all built-in/standard identifiers for cases like this:

```
>>> import __builtin__
>>>
>>> __builtin__.max is max
True
>>>
>>> max = 2
>>> __builtin__.max([0, max])
2
```

```
import __builtin__ as builtins

def random_integer(min, max):
    random_integer.seed = builtins.max(10101, ( # looks random enough, right?
        ((random_integer.seed * 3 - 210) % 9898989) >> 1) ^ 173510713571)
    return min + (random_integer.seed % (max - min + 1))

random_integer.seed = 123456789
```

> This module is not normally accessed explicitly by most applications, but can be useful in modules that provide objects with the same name as a built-in value, but in which the built-in of that name is also needed.

The name change in Python 3 is part of [the "core languages" changes described in PEP 3100](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3100/#core-language):

> In order to get rid of the confusion between `__builtin__` and `__builtins__`, it was decided to rename `__builtin__` (the module) to `builtins`, and to leave `__builtins__` (the sandbox hook) alone.

Comment: The name of the module changed between Python 2 and Python 3? Interesting.

Comment: Then you can do `__builtins__.max = 2` and really cause trouble!