# Is it a bad practice to name a instance variable after a built-in

Tags: python, reserved-words, built-in

Having variables named after python built-ins is a bad practice, because it [prevents their proper usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470018/using-pythons-max-function-when-you-have-a-variable-named-max), and may confuse readers.

But what about an instance variable:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, type_):
        self.type = type_
```

Is there a good argument against this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say it's ok.

Grepping through Python's standard library you can see plenty of places where attributes are named the same as built-ins:

For example:

```
:~/cpython/Lib$ egrep -R "\.set[^a-zA-Z0-9_]" | wc -l
583
:~/cpython/Lib$ egrep -R "\.type[^a-zA-Z0-9_]" | wc -l
319
```

Comment: Users of the `.type` idiom include `argparse`, `optparse`, `tarfile` and `urllib`. Considering these got accepted into cPython, it's good enough for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Would `some_object.type != type(some_object)` be confusing ? Yes , to me at the very least. So there's your own good argument against it : *it may confuse readers*.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure someone is gonna find this *opinion based*...

**However**, here goes mine:

No, is not a bad practice. Those class attributes are just fields into the `__dict__` area of your *instance* (mgnmgnmnnn... fine, or the `__slots__`), and thus are instance bound. You can't mistake `self.type` with the built-in `type` (the `self.type` always needs to be accessed with the `self.`), so you're implicitly limiting the scope... Is a bit (a **bit**) like what happens with a variable called `path` when you have `from os import path`...

If you have:

```
from os import path
path="/home/borrajax/foo.txt"
path.join(path, ...)  # Eeeeeeermmm... I'm kind of screwed here?
```

However, if you do:

```
import os
path="/home/borrajax/foo.txt"
os.path.join(path, ...)
```

You're perfectly fine, because your scope is clear.

The way **I see it** (and maybe someone might disagree) is that classes/instances limit the scope in a similar way. When you see `self.type`, you know it has to be bound to an instance!!

However, you are kind of... erm... yeah... If you attempt to overwrite built in attributes for classes:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = "foo"
        self.a = "hi"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A()
```

Will give you:

```
$ python ./stack_055_B.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./stack_055_B.py", line 7, in <module>
    a = A()
  File "./stack_055_B.py", line 3, in __init__
    self.__dict__ = "foo"
TypeError: __dict__ must be set to a dictionary, not a 'str'
```